# m2e ignores the testOutputDirectory for test resources

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a requirement to output my build to a different directory to **target**.

Using the **project.build.directory**, **output** and **testOutputDirectory** properties works correctly from the command line using `mvn clean install`, but when I build from eclipse it creates an empty `target/test-classes` directory if I have a `src/test/resources` directory.

A simple pom file that has the same behavior looks like:

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>reproduce</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.directory>differentTarget</project.build.directory>
        <project.build.outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</project.build.outputDirectory>
        <project.build.testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/different-test-classes</project.build.testOutputDirectory>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</testOutputDirectory>
    </build>
</project>
```

My directory structure looks like:

```
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----webapp
   |-------WEB-INF
   |---test
   |-----resources
```

The simplest way I can reproduce the behavior is with all the directories empty except for a web.xml with `<web-app />` inside it.

When I have actual test classes it creates folders inside the `target/test-classes` directory but then puts the actual class files in `differentTarget/test-classes`.

I am using *Eclipse Indigo*, *m2e 1.2.0* and *Maven Integration for WTP 0.15.3* on *Debian*

**Edit**

If I remove the `properties` and hard code the outputs:

```
<build>
    <directory>differentTarget</directory>
    <outputDirectory>differentTarget/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>differentTarget/different-test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
</build>
```

Then I get the correct behavior when I go **Maven > Update Project...** but I still get the incorrect target folder when I go **Project > Clean** or more importantly have it on **Build Automatically** .

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0) approach?

Comment: I have seen that in a few other places but it was not useful in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking your output folders for your Java Build Path. The m2e plugin might be failing to update all the output paths:

Right click your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path.

On the Source tab expand each entry, edit the Output Folder and switch each one back to the project default.

Comment: This fixed it. It had `target/test-classes` as the output folder

Answer (score 1):

By default all maven POM inherit the Super POM. If you have a look at the [Maven Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html), you can see **testOutputDirectory** is defined as an element under project/build. I'm not sure if you meant to set it as a property. Try override the element <testOutputDirectory> directly under your <build> section

Comment: If I remove the properties and use the **testOutputDirectory** directly I get the same behavior `<testOutputDirectory>differentTarget/different-test-classes</testOutputDirectory>`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes m2e does not pick up changes.

So select your project, **right mouse click -> Maven -> Update Project**.

[image]

If that doesn't help, remove the .settings folder and try again.

**Edit:**

Maybe it can't translate the properties used in the build section. Try hardcoded:

```
 <build>
    <directory>differentTarget</directory>
    <outputDirectory>differentTarget/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>differentTarget/different-test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
 </build>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both of those but still get the same result. Even if I only have empty directories except for the web.xml and import it as a new project it gives the same behavior.

Comment: I tried that for @gerrytan answer and unfortunately it still gives the same result of creating a target folder.

Comment: Just tried it in a test pom, and the above works. Are you sure the Update Project does not help?

Comment: **update project configuration from pom.xml** is ticked. I get the correct behavior when I go **Maven > Update Project** but still the incorrect behavior when Eclipse builds the project through **Project > Clean** or the automatic build